# Unsupported serialization format on REST/Delete request

Tags: 8

I'm getting the following error on my custom resource when sending the following DELETE request even though POST and GET are working fine

*"A fatal error occurred: Serialization for the format  is not supported"*

The request looks as follows:

[image]

If I'd change the method from DELETE to GET it would return status 200 with the intended - and for testing purposes identical - behaviour. The configuration in the Rest UI module looks as the following and the permissions for the requests (GET, POST and DELETE) are allowed for Guests:

[image: Rest UI]

Here is the code of my custom class:

```
/**
 * Provides a Demo Resource
 *
 * @RestResource(
 *   id = "test_resource",
 *   label = @Translation("Demo Resource"),
 *   uri_paths = {
 *      "canonical" = "/test_rest_api/test/{email}",
         "https://www.drupal.org/link-relations/create" = "/test_rest_api/test",
 *   }
 * )
 */
class TestResource extends ResourceBase {
  //Here are construct and create functions

  /**
   * Responds to entity GET requests.
   *
   * Does something
   *
   * @return \Drupal\rest\ResourceResponse
   */
   public function get($email) {
    $message = ["message" => $email];
    return new ResourceResponse($message);
   }

  /**
   * Responds to entity POST requests.
   *
   * Does something
   *
   * @param $data
   * @return \Drupal\rest\ResourceResponse
   */
  public function post(array $data = []) {
    $message = ["message" => $data["email"]];
    return new ResourceResponse($message);
  }

  /**
   * Responds to entity DELETE requests.
   *
   * Does something
   *
   * @return \Drupal\rest\ResourceResponse
   */
  public function delete($email) {
    $message = ["message" => $email];
    return new ResourceResponse($message);
  }
}
```

Has somebody an idea what I'm overlooking? I disabled/enabled the resource multiple and cleared the cache multiple times

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In delete method you can not return **ResourceResponse**. Try return **ModifiedResourceResponse**.

```
return new ModifiedResourceResponse(NULL, 204);
```

Notice: First argument of **ModifiedResourceResponse** need are NULL, if your specific data for this parameter  throw same error.

Comment: Your method also works with the normal *ResourceResponse*, but according to https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!modules!rest!src!ModifiedResourceResponse.php/8.3.x *ModifiedResourceResponse* is the way to go.

Answer (score 3):

Also in DELETE method if you want to return a response you could use
 return new JsonResponse('Processed'); including the following use statement:
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;

Comment: Yes really good way for confirm delete.

Answer (score 1):

With the help of @OPTASY's answer, I was able to return a response to the client's DELETE request. For example:

```
public function delete($email) {
  $message = ["message" => $email];
  return new JsonResponse(message);
}
```

Be sure to include `JsonResponse` at the top of your file:

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;
```